# Meteor Router crashing - Cannot call method 'filters' of undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a page that I want the user to not be able to access unless they have a certain property. I have defined a filter as such:

```
Meteor.Router.filters({ //line 24
  isX: function(page) {
    if(Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['X'])) {
      return page;
    } else {
      return '/error';
    }
  }
});

Meteor.Router.filter(isX, {only : 'xPage'});
```

this code exists in my router.js file. When I try to compile it I get the following error:

> ```
> \.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
>                       throw(ex);
>                             ^
>     TypeError: Cannot call method 'filters' of undefined
>         at app\lib\router.js:24:15
>         at app\lib\router.js:70:3 //end of file
>         at \.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:222:10
>         at Array.forEach (native)
>         at Function._.each._.forEach (\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
>         at \.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:117:5
>     Exited with code: 8
>     Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
> ```

I'm at a loss because this is pretty much straight out of the examples for iron router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are getting `Meteor.Router.filters` with regards to `iron:router`. You can do something very similar to what you need with an `onBeforeAction` though.

```
var isX = function() {
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ["X"])) {
        this.next();
    }
    else {
        this.redirect("/error");
    }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(isX, {
    only: ["xPage"]
});

Router.route("/xPage", {
    name: "xPage",
    action: function() {
        this.render("xPage");
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm, I was looking at the documentation for the now deprecated Meteor Router. I'd like to thank the Academy and my mom for this high point in my life